# jQuery .print() works on window but not on element

Tags: jquery

This works:

```
$(".printButton").click(function(v){
    v.preventDefault()      
    window.print();
});
```

This dosen't work (prevents default but dosen't print):

```
$(".printButton").click(function(v){
    v.preventDefault()
    $("#content").print();
});
```

Any suggestions what the problem is?

Comment: jQuery doesn't have a `print` method.

Comment: You can’t print one element, and `jQuery.fn.print` doesn’t exist anyways. When you do `window.print`, jQuery is not implicated.

Comment: what are you trying to do by the way..?

Comment: I want to print the page without the navigation bar. Calling .hide() on the navigation, then window.print(); and then .show() on the navigation works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

print() is available only on window object, it's not JQuery object, Please refer this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_print.asp) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536672(v=vs.85).aspx)